# please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

Despite looking over more than 3 post (made in 2015) about this problem, non have solved mine.

When ever I run, a simple, code to draw a line using UIBezierPath the program would return me this:

> : CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> : CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you
>   want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
>   environmental variable.
>
> : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see
>   the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to
>   see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see
>   the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see
>   the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0. If you want to
>   see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see
>   the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the
>   backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see
>   the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.
>
> : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to
>   see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.

```
@interface line : UIView
UIBezierPath *myPath;
.........
@implementation
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
myPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myPath moveToPoint:touchLocation];
}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
[myPath addLineToPoint:touchLocation];
[[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
[[UIColor greenColor]setFill];
[myPath stroke];
}
```

If I was to draw using drawRect

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
....
}
```

No error would pop up. I was wondering If I was receiving these errors because `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` can't perform drawing?

In cocoa (OS X) I used to use `setNeedsDisplay`, but it doesn't exist in cocoa touch.

All I'm asking is, is there anyway to remove these errors or is there another way to draw `UIBezierPath` during run time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Invalid context errors happen, because you are trying to use drawing operations outside of `drawRect:` method, so no current graphic context is set.

Like on OS X, you should perform drawing in `drawRect:` method, and use `setNeedsDisplay` to update resulting image. And both `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` methods are available for UIView on iOS.

So, result should look like this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
myPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[myPath moveToPoint:touchLocation];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
[myPath addLineToPoint:touchLocation];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
[[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
[[UIColor greenColor]setFill];
[myPath stroke];
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and was trying to call drawRect to force a  redraw of some graphics code my view draws when it loads. I was trying to put my own value in the drawRect parameter. Using setNeedsDisplay instead fixed my problem.