# invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I use this code, there will be an error

```
+ (UIImage *)createImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,size.width,size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return theImage;
}
```

Error log 。Not creash,  Not status bar relationship

Comment: try to see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764459/please-set-cg-context-show-backtrace-environmental-variable

Comment: I tried, can not solve

Answer (score 0):

I just have tried this code,it works properly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *image = [self createImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (UIImage *)createImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,size.width,size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return theImage;
}
```

Comment: @PengfeiGuo could you post the code where you call it

Comment: - (UIImageView *)iconImageView{
    if (!_iconImageView) {
        _iconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        _iconImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _iconImageView.image = [ImageUtils createImageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:_iconImageView.size];
    }
    return _iconImageView;
}

Comment: Do you set the frame of your imageview？